# Yosemite taking too long to show login screen

Tags: macos, startup

When I turn on my iMac ( 16 GB, Intel Processor 3.1 Ghz, Fusion drive year 2013) now it takes too long for the log in screen to appear. Before that I see a gray screen with a progress bar at the bottom but it takes about 2 minutes !! That did not happen with Mavericks

Comment: Do you have FileVault enabled? The only times I have seen the progress bar is when the hard drive is encrypted or during system updates. 
Try resetting PRAM+NVRAM: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Thanks for your comments. FileVault is not enabled and tried resetting PRAM+NVRAM and it didn´t work. Curiously, my son´s MAC also suffers the same problem since updated to Yosemite. As for the rest, the machine is working perfectly, it`s only this eternal windows type booting!!! Hope Apple finds a solution to the problem